# Lost byte when download file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, webclient, dotnet-httpclient

I have three applications. 
First: IIS
Second: Service (ASP.NET MVC)
Third: Client(Winform)

Files are store on IIS. 
Service public an api to download file as byte array base on URL. Client call api of Service and store file by extension.

After Client call Service, I check on Service, it return 15500 bytes. But I catch on Client, it is 13 bytes.

Below is the code on Service:

```
[HttpGet]
        public byte[] DownloadData(string serverUrlAddress, string path)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(serverUrlAddress) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path))
                return null;

        // Create a new WebClient instance
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            // Concatenate the domain with the Web resource filename.
            string url = string.Concat(serverUrlAddress, "/", path);
            if (url.StartsWith("http://") == false)
                url = "http://" + url;

            byte[] data = client.DownloadData(url);
            return data;
        }
    }
```

Below is the code on Client:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] data = GetData();
            File.WriteAllBytes(@"E:\a.pdf", data);
        }
    public static byte[] GetData()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:54220/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("API/File/DownloadData?serverUrlAddress=www.x.com&path=Data/Folder/file.pdf").Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var yourcustomobjects = response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
                return yourcustomobjects;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When returning CLR types Web API attempts to serialize the object based on either Xml or Json serializers.  Neither of these are what you want.  You want to return the raw stream of bytes.  Try this.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage DownloadData(string serverUrlAddress, string path)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(serverUrlAddress) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path))
            return null;

    // Create a new WebClient instance
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        // Concatenate the domain with the Web resource filename.
        string url = string.Concat(serverUrlAddress, "/", path);
        if (url.StartsWith("http://") == false)
            url = "http://" + url;

        byte[] data = client.DownloadData(url);
        return new HttpResponseMessage() { Content = new StreamContent(data) };
    }
}
```

By returning a HttpResponseMessage you have more control over exactly how Web API returns the response.  By default StreamContent will set the Content-Type header to be `application/octet-stream`.  You may want to change that to  'application/pdf' if you are always returning PDF files.